# sql calculated column when find words

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to accomplish the following. 
There is a calculated field I need to create that sums the rows when it finds a specific word. Something like this:

```
SELECT sum(
    case 
        when product.description like'%trans%'
            or product.description like '%transitions%' 
          then sales 
        else null 
    end
    ) as transitions
```

How can I search for multiple words in a column using the conditional case to sum only the rows that have these words?

Comment: What is the issue with your approach?

Comment: You should take care about Upper/Lower case. Try this: `SELECT sum(case when lower(p.description) like'%trans%' then p.sales else null end) as transitions FROM Product AS p`

Comment: Are you sure you want the % before and after your keywords? Otherwise it looks fine to me

Comment: Consider creating a special column `SMALLINT NOT NULL`, that would be +1 if any of watched words appeared and 0 if it did not. You would update this column value from the `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: Thanks Arioch, I will take that advice.

Comment: Also in FB3 it can be Boolean column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your particular example is poor because `'%trans%'` matches `'%transitions%'`.  So, this is sufficient for your example:

```
SELECT sum(case when product.description like '%trans%'
                then sales
           end) as transitions
```

You can search for other things using `or`:

```
SELECT sum(case when product.description like '%trans%' or
                     product.description like '%cis%'
                then sales
           end) as transitions
```

Note that if you are looking for *words* in `product.description` then perhaps a text field is not the right structure (that is, perhaps you should be storing each word separately).  Alternatively, you might want to look into full-text search.

Comment: please check my comment to the question.

Comment: Thank you Gordon your explanation has solved my issue. regards